# duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/analytics/internal/Command.class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-analytics

I am having an error

> packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'. java.util.zip.ZipException:
>   duplicate entry:
>   com/google/android/gms/analytics/internal/Command.class

This  is my gradle

```
dependencies {

compile project(':simonVTLibrary')
compile project(':facebookSDK')
compile project(':library')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
compile files('libs/crashlytics.jar')
compile files('libs/InMobi-4.1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
compile files('libs/PayPalAndroidSDK-2.5.1.jar')
compile files('libs/picasso-2.4.0.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

}
```

I think I am having duplicate between 'libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar' and 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+' .I have been searching and can't find an answer. What workaround I need to do?

Comment: You are bringing in Google Play services twice. Do not use Jars.

Answer (score 2):

Dependency

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services:+
```

already contains the google analytics library, you shouldn't add the local jar manually. Also, if you need only Google Analytics, i'd recommend you to use separate module

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0
```

which would contain only dependencies, necessary for Google Analyticals

Comment: No. The OP is bringing in GPS twice.

Comment: @JaredBurrows yeah, I know. That's what I said above.